# present continuous or present simple?

Tags: grammar, present-continuous, present-simple

Which of the following sentences is correct?

> "*I wasn't very well yesterday, but I'm feeling fine today.*"

or

> "*I wasn't very well yesterday, but I feel fine today.*"

Comment: Also *I **wasn't feeling** very well yesterday, but **I'm fine** today*, etc. They're all perfectly "correct", and mean the same thing.

Comment: Isn't present simple for general ideas? For example: I work in a hospital. But, feelings change frequently, so I think we should use present continuous. What do you think?

Comment: I think most native speakers wouldn't distinguish between ***wasn't feeling*** and ***didn't feel*** in your context, just as they wouldn't normally distinguish between ***I don't feel well*** and ***I'm not feeling well***. But non-native speakers should probably prefer the simple (non-continuous) verb forms, because there are many other contexts where the continuous *doesn't* work (for example, *I'm not liking this* is very unlikely compared to *I **don't like** this*). In which context, McDonald's ***I'm lovin' it*** is a deliberately chosen / masterfully memorable "slightly weird" slogan.